# Disable typing in textarea

Tags: html, angular, typescript

**I want to disable the user from typing in textarea, when word count limit is reached. But the user should be able to edit the text within the given limit.**

**I used attr.disabled property to disable from typing. But, this just blocks the user from typing and editing. I want to do this in angular.**

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Could you please try `maxLength` attribute? it can forbid the any keyPress once met the max length.

Comment: Check the field value length property and return any keypress if the length is greater than your limit. That's the simple logic of it.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but max length just takes the count of the character, but I need word count. I've used a function to take wordcount

Comment: you can use ng-click option

Comment: as a easy way use maxLength attribute and use like your defaut max count + spaces count

Answer (score 13):

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-awsvcs) put this in component to count spaces

```
check(){
    return this.test.split(" ").length-1;
    
  }
```

in html

```
<textarea 
    [(ngModel)]="test"
    name=".."
    placeholder="..."
    [maxLength]="10+check()"
   >
</textarea>
```

If you think function occurs performance loses then use `(keypress)` method and create attribute as `ex_length=0;` then in component.ts

```
keypress(){
    this.ex_length=this.test.split(" ").length-1; 
}
```

in html

```
<textarea 
    [(ngModel)]="test"
    name=".."
    placeholder="..."
    (keypress)="onkeypress()"
    [maxLength]="10+ex_length"
   >
</textarea>
```

or as other way you can use custom pipe [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gdxepk?file=src/app/app.component.html)

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'max'
})
export class MaxPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any): any {
    return 10 + value.split(" ").length-1;
  }

}
```

an in html

```
<textarea 
    [(ngModel)]="test"
    name=".."
    placeholder="..."
    [maxLength]="test | max"
   >
</textarea>
```